# Symfony2 FileType input in form always returns null

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony-forms

I'm working on a way to upload a .pdf file on my website.

I've created an Entity which contains the name of the file in a string.
There is the entity mapping:

```
<field name="pdf" type="string" column="pdf" length="200" nullable="true"/>
```

The form where I input the file:

```
$builder
        ->add('pdf', FileType::class, array('label' => 'Fiche de paie'))
        /* other input */
    ;
```

The view of my form:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_row(form._token) }}
    <div class="modal-body row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-8">
            /* other input */
            {{ form_row(form.pdf) }}}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-8">
            /* other input */
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="save">{% trans %}Save{% endtrans %}</button>
    </div>
    {{ form_end(form, { 'render_rest': false } ) }}
```

And there is the Controller:

```
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $pdf = $salaire->getPdf();

        if ($pdf == null) { /* Always true */
            $salaire->setPdf('test');
        }

        /* operations to extract the file name and set it to the pdf variable in salaire */

        $em->persist($salaire);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('salaires_index', array("id" => $remuneration->getId()));
    }
```

The problem is that even if I input a file, when i get the value of the input with

```
->salaire->getPdf()
```

the result is always null.

First I thought It was because I set the form input FileType on a string in my entity, but I've tried to set it on a UploadedFile variable in my entity and the result is still null.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to set the correct enctype of the form element (in the form tag the value `enctype="multipart/form-data"`).

Referring to the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html#form-variables-reference) you can do something like:

```
{{ form_start(form, {'multipart': true}) }}
```

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks for your help, but that didn't make it.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. The uploaded file had always null value. I found that the controller's form handling was incorrect.

Originally I had something like this:

```
if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
    $form->submit($request->request->get($form->getName()));
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    // handle form data
    }
}
```

All the other fields provided their value so it has been working until I added the FileType element. This has fixes the problem:

```
$form->handleRequest($request);  // This bit was important
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
// handle form data
}
```